# How to combine tags in pandas dataframe using str.format?

Tags: python, pandas

This is basically a pandas syntax question.

I have a dataframe that contains, among other things, rows that are tagged with a Quantification and a Calibration, both of which are text. There are >100,000 rows, but only ~200 unique Quantification tags and ~10 unique Calibration tags. I'm trying to concatenate these into a single tag, and I ran into a curiosity:

this works:

```
df['n_q'] = df['Quantification'] + " (" + df['Calibration'] + ')'
```

but this doesn't:

```
df['n_q'] = "{0} ({1})".format(df['Quantification'], df['Calibration'])
```

The latter seems to make give every row the same, giant string that I guess is all the tags concatenated.

My question is how can I do what I want to do using str.format?

Comment: You shouldn't use `all` as a variable name as it overwrites the built-in `all` function.

Comment: Thanks. I changed 'all' to 'df'.

Comment: You don't say why you don't like the solution you have? Writing about that might sometimes create ideas for completely different solution paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use an apply:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df['A'] + ' (' + df['B'] + ')'
Out[12]: 
0    a (b)
1    c (d)
dtype: object

In [13]: df.apply(lambda x: '{0} ({1})'.format(*x), axis=1)
Out[13]: 
0    a (b)
1    c (d)
dtype: object
```

*Note: this work when you are using all columns.*

You can reference by column names for a neater and more robust solution:

```
In [14]: df.apply(lambda x: '{A} ({B})'.format(**x), axis=1)
Out[14]:
0    a (b)
1    c (d)
dtype: object
```

Comment: That's simple! One criticism: doing format(*x) assumes there aren't other columns. One can replace it with format(x['Quantification'], x['Calibration']).

Comment: @user3417592 that's a great point, it's better to use the names, I edited in a neater syntax to do just that!